# How do I set the Gerrit 'Push merge commit' permission

Tags: git, merge, push, gerrit

I'm told that, in gerrit, if I want to submit merges (Instead of rebasing), then I need to allow 'push merge commit' permissions. 
Right now I get the message: (You are not allowed to upload merges).

I can't seem to find anywhere that actually states HOW I set this permission. Is it a setting on gerrit? Something in the config file etc.?

So where do I set the 'Push merge commit' permission?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the Gerrit GUI

1. Click on "Projects"
2. Click on "List"
3. Use the "Filter" field to find the desired project
4. Click on the project name
5. Click in "Access"
6. Click in "Edit"
7. In "refs/for/refs/*" section add "Push Merge Commit" ALLOW permission to the desired group
8. Click in "Save Changes"

Note: you need to have "Administrate Server" rights.

More info: https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/access-control.html#category_push_merge

To be more specific, add the following lines in your `project.config` file

```
[access "refs/for/refs/*"]
  pushMerge = group <your-id-here>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The confusion was that I didn't realise there was the "Administrate server" level of permission rights, above my own level of project administrator. So it turns out these access controls are not available to me.

Comment: What is a group in this context? A Unix group? A system username? Something on Gerrit? I've found this answer but am no closer to understanding how to actually grant permission to someone.

Comment: It's a Gerrit group (click on BROWSE > Groups to see the available groups). If you use LDAP, you can use LDAP groups too. If Gerrit has the "singleusergroup" plugin installed, you can use a username too.